# Will trigram index on multiple columns make search faster and how to make such search properly?

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

Let's assume I have table with multiple columns. For instance:

```
id int
name text
surname text
cars json
```

example record would be

```
+----+------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | name | surname |              cars                  |
+----+------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | John | Doe     | {"values":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]} |
+----+------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

I want to search all this table data for relevance like this:

```
select *,
       similarity(
          'Malcolm Joe likes Ferrary, but hates BMW',
          (name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)
       ) sim
from public.test_table
where similarity(
         'Malcolm Joe likes Ferrary, but hates BMW',
         (name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)
      ) > 0.05
order by sim desc;
```

Is there any way to speed up this search? Creating a trigram index? If so - how to create it better? on one column, on each column, on a concatenation expression? Also, I haven't understand which type of index is better - GIN or GiST. I've read that GIN is usually better for regular full text search, but GiST is better for trigram search. Is that correct?

I also wanted to ask if there is better way to write the above query?

If anyone wonders why I chose trigram, and not regular full text search - it's because search strings will come from processing some user input, so there can be mistakes or even cases when english 'o' or 'c' is replaced by cirillic letters. my database records or search can also contain alphanumeric data, which is also better processed with trigram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need a GiST index, because only that can be used with `ORDER BY` queries using the trigram distance operator:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.test_table USING gist
   ((name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname) gist_trgm_ops);
```

The query should then be rewritten to:

```
SELECT *,
       similarity(
          'Malcolm Joe likes Ferrary, but hates BMW',
          (name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)
       ) sim
FROM public.test_table
WHERE ((name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)
       <->
       'Malcolm Joe likes Ferrary, but hates BMW')
      < 0.95
ORDER BY (name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)
         <->   /* trigram distance */
         'Malcolm Joe likes Ferrary, but hates BMW'
LIMIT 50;
```

The query had to be rewritten, because there is index support for `<->`, but not for `similarity()` in `ORDER BY` expressions.

I added the `LIMIT` to hint the optimizer, put in a limit as appropriate.

I *think* that in general GIN indexes perform better for large tables, but I am not certain. You have no choice with this query anyway, because GIN indexes won't support that `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why you chose <-> (distance) over "similarity > threshold"? Does it perform better because of second part (which is "order by desc") in my case? I'm very new to world of full text search so "order by sim desc" seems equal to "order by (name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname) <-> 'search expression'"

Comment: You are right, it is identical in its semantics. But a function expression cannot be indexed, while an operator can. Actually, that [is no longer true](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-optimization.html) as of PostgreSQL v12, but nobody has written a planner support function for `similarity` yet. I have improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you would want to create the index on the expression `(name || (cars ->> 'values') || surname)`.  However, your example itself doesn't make sense.  It is valid SQL, but why in the world would you want to do it?  Why would you compare an English sentence, to a string consisting of someone's full name but with a blob of JSON injected into the middle of it?  This is important, because your example only has one row, so the index doesn't matter.  So we have to extrapolate your example to a large number of rows, where an index would matter.  But since it doesn't make any real-world sense, how can we extrapolate it up in a sensible way?

> Also, I haven't understand which type of index is better - GIN or GiST. I've read that GIN is usually better for regular full text search, but GiST is better for trigram search. Is that correct?

Not generally so in my experience.  GiST trigram indexes are signature based, where each trigram sets a bit in the signature.  But there are way more trigrams than there are bits, so they are heavily overloaded. These types of indexes only perform well when they are lightly populated.  (But it is hard to say what "lightly populated" means ahead of time, other they "try it with your real dataset and see".)  Given their unpredictability, I avoid GiST indexes unless there is a clear benefit to them, which I don't see here.

Given your query, you could use either kind of index, but would have to write it differently.  Also, it is doubtful that either index would help because in

```
similarity(x,exp) > 0.05
```

the cutoff of 0.05 is so lax, that few rows will probably get rejected by the index.

If you had a higher cutoff, like 0.5, then with a GIN index would formulate it like:

```
set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.5;
select ... from test_table where x % exp order by x <-> exp ;
```

This will extract everything sufficiently similar, then sort them by the distance. If few enough things are "sufficiently similar", this gives pretty good performance (and if not, you should revisit your choice of pg_trgm.similarity_threshold). As Laurenz Albe says, with a GiST index you can extract the rows already in order and then stop once the LIMIT is reached, but in the absence of a LIMIT clause, this is of no value.